# Transit visa in China for a Nepali citizen

Tags: transit-visas, china, nepali-citizens

I have Nepali citizenship.  I have a flight from Sydney to Kathmandu with stops in China.  Do I need a transit visa?  I already bought the online ticket.

Here is my itinerary.

```
Outbound
FLIGHT: MU 792 - China Eastern  24/12/2019
DEPARTURE:  Sydney, AU (Kingsford Smith)    24/12/2019 11:30
ARRIVAL:    Beijing, CN (Capital Intl)  24/12/2019 23:30
AIRLINE BOOKING REFERENCE: MU/XXXXXX
BOOKING CONFIRMED: , Economy    DURATION: 11:00

BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE:  2 Pieces
STOPS:  1
OPERATED BY:    China Eastern, MU



FLIGHT: MU 2035 - China Eastern 25/12/2019
DEPARTURE:  Beijing, CN (Capital Intl)  25/12/2019 05:55
ARRIVAL:    Kunming, CN (Kunming)   25/12/2019 10:00
AIRLINE BOOKING REFERENCE: MU/XXXXXX
BOOKING CONFIRMED: , Economy    DURATION: 04:05

BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE:  2 Pieces
STOPS:  -
OPERATED BY:    China Eastern, MU


FLIGHT: MU 757 - China Eastern  25/12/2019
DEPARTURE:  Kunming, CN (Kunming)   25/12/2019 14:30
ARRIVAL:    Kathmandu, NP (Kathmandu)   25/12/2019 15:55
AIRLINE BOOKING REFERENCE: MU/XXXXXX
BOOKING CONFIRMED: , Economy    DURATION: 03:40

BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE:  2 Pieces
STOPS:  -
OPERATED BY:    China Eastern, MU
```

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: My citizenship is Nepali

Comment: It looks like MU792 SYD-PEK has a stop in Nanjing (NKG), so you actually have three stops in China: Nanjing, Beijing and Kunming.

Comment: By the way, you edited the Sydney departure time from 11:30 to 1:30, but it looks like 11:30 is correct so I changed it back.

Comment: Your flight is tomorrow and you're asking about visas today?